# What steps does gcc(or g++) take in searching for the location of libaries?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

When using the -l flag in a c++ makefile, I couldn't find information on what steps gcc takes in searching for that library.

For clarity of what I'm asking, I'll make up an example answer (this is completely made up):

1. First searches the -L flag directory
2. Next searches the /lib directory
3. Something something etc

---

Some extra info:

The reason I'm stuck in this is because I currently have a program that uses libconfig in the makefile like so:

```
g++ $(CFLAGS) -o libvldsk_config.so $(SRCDIR)/config.cpp -Wall -shared -fPIC -I$(SRCDIR) -I$(COMMON_SRCDIR) -lconfig
```

but this was made assuming that libconfig is installed via a package manager. I installed via source because the linux version was too old to have it in a package manager. And so I'm trying to modify my program that uses libconfig to search for the libconfig .so file in the system's /lib directory, and if it doesn't exist search for it in the current project directory.

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: The actual question is as the title.

Comment: Try gcc -print-search-dirs

Comment: Unrecognized option "-print" and unrecognized option "-search". Maybe this gcc is too old? (I'm working on RHEL 4)

Comment: @CuriousKimchiNoob sounds like you put a space after `-print`

Comment: "What's your actual problem?" ==> "What is the error you're getting? What is the problem that is causing you to post here?"

Comment: You can use `gcc -v` (as well as your other options) to see what the compiler runs to link your program.  Where did you install `libconfig.a` or `libconfig.so`?  Unless that's in `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/lib` or `/lib` (or the appropriate 64-bit alternative directories if you're building for 64-bit), then you need to add a `-L/where/you/put/libconfig` (where that's the name of a directory containing the `libconfig.{a,so}` file (possibly `-L.` if it is in the current directory).  Note that if it is a shared object (`.so`), you need to find the library at run-time too; use `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is going off-tangent, but in relation to your comment, an interesting thing happened where I call "make install" for libconfig, and it created the libconfig.so files in my /usr/local/lib. With this, my program that uses libconfig compiled fine, but it would not find the appropriate .so file at runtime. Only if I set the "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" would it find the file. What do you think is the issue here?

Comment: Check `/etc/ld.so.conf` or the equivalent file — see whether the dynamic loader looks in `/usr/local/lib` or not.  You may need to use `ldconfig` to help you find out what the configuration is and/or to change it.

Comment: It does not have `/usr/local/lib`. But neither does it have `/lib`.